# Disable scrolling bar in mat menu

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to make the scroll bar in a material menu disappear but I don't seem to be able to do it.

As it is right now:

[image: As it is]

As I want it to be:

[image: As i want it]

I've tried the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267462/how-to-remove-angular-material-design-menu-box-scroll-bars) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165401/how-to-disable-scroll-in-md-menu), without success.

I know that the option I must set in the css is `overflow: hidden;` but this does not seem to do the trick when I put it in the component css.

I've tried setting that option to `.mat-menu-panel`, `.mat-menu` and even with a custom class, but it does not work.

My html looks like this:

```html
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="employee_name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="rest"> Nombre </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.employee_name}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="rest"> Fecha </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="duration">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="rest"> Duración </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.duration}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="menu"></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
          <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
            <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="menu-without-scroll">
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="editDuration(element)">
              <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
              <span>Editar</span>
            </button>
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="deleteDuration(element)">
              <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
              <span>Eliminar</span>
            </button>
          </mat-menu>
        </td>

      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedComumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedComumns;" (click)="onEdit(row)"></tr>
    </mat-table>
```

The menu is in one of the cells of the table.

From the developer tools in the browser if I change in `.mat-menu-panel` `overflow: auto` to `overflow:hidden` it renders correctly but if I change it in the .css it does not work.

The dependencies, in case it helps, are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.12",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

Tell me if you need more information.

Comment: please share the jsfiddle link. thanks

Comment: Did you try `overflow-y:hidden` ?

Comment: @A.Bechir yes, I did try it does not seem to work either, even tried `overflow:hidden !important`

Comment: So please share jsfiddle link

Comment: Why are you using AngularJS Material with Angular Material?

Comment: @A.Bechir OP is using Angular, the newer framework. AFAIK, it's not possible to have an Angular project on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because , when you using angular one common attribute will be rendered in DOM like 
ng-content which will over write your class properties written in css , so try this code this will eliminate native angular styles to use in application .

Go to the Component,

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
```

then

```
@Component({
.....
.....
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

then your styles will taken by browser .

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a couple years old, but the last answer can cause serious issues with css classes from your own style bleeding into child elements. Sure, you can now overwrite css styles from sub-components easily, but it also means you can easily overwrite them unintentionally. `ViewEncapsulation.None` should not be used unless absolutely necessary.

Instead, it's better to use `::ng-deep` ([see the reference](https://ngrefs.com/latest/styling/ng-deep-selector)) to specify when you would like to override a sub-component's styling.

In your case, you'd be able to do the following:

```
::ng-deep .menu-without-scroll {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Note that while `::ng-deep` is deprecated, there is currently no alternative and hence it's reasonable to continue using it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49308475/5158280) for more info.